# Notification - cannot resolve symbol setLastEvenInfo

Tags: android, notifications

Months ago I wrote a code that my `Notification` worked as bellow :

```
NotificationManager NotiManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String MyText = "NotificationText";
Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.mipmap.icon, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );

mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
mNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
mNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

String MyNotificationTitle = "AnyText";
String MyNotificationText  = "HERE MORE TEXT";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context.getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);
NotiManager.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID_LOGIN, mNotification);
```

But now, that I want to make an update it doesn't even let compile the APP because this line :

```
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context.getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);
```

Is there any way to change the `setLatestEventInfo` or other way to create a `Notification`?

Comment: you should start using [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

Comment: @Blackbelt It's almost the same as I was doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the setLatestEventInfo

You are welcome to lower your `compileSdkVersion`, though that will introduce its own set of issues.

> or other way to create a Notification?

As Blackbelt notes in a comment, `NotificationCompat.Builder` has been around for ~4 years and is the recommended way to create `Notification` objects today:

```
  private void raiseNotification(String mimeType, File output,
                                 Exception e) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    if (e == null) {
      b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.download_complete))
       .setContentText(getString(R.string.fun))
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
       .setTicker(getString(R.string.download_complete));

      Intent outbound=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

      outbound.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), mimeType);

      b.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, outbound, 0));
    }
    else {
      b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.exception))
       .setContentText(e.getMessage())
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
       .setTicker(getString(R.string.exception));
    }

    NotificationManager mgr=
        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, b.build());
  }
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/DownloadNotify), which is in [this directory of sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications) all showing how to display `Notifications`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CommonsWare, one question... on my NotificationManager I was adding the NotificationTitle and NotificationText where I put it now, on NotificationCompat.Builder? And now isn't necessary the `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: @Skizo: "where I put it now, on NotificationCompat.Builder?" -- `setContextText()` and `setContentTitle()`. "And now isn't necessary the System.currentTimeMillis()?" -- the default is `System.currentTimeMillis()` now. You can call `setWhen()` if there is some other milliseconds-since-the-Unix-epoch value that you wish to use.

Comment: Alright! I think it's better and easier to use `NotificationCompat.Builder` many thanks ;).