# setLatestEventInfo is deprecated I'm aware but how do I fix my code now?

Tags: android

First of all I'm a beginner so bear with me if I miss out on something or don't get something easily. I'm working on this project the functions used were deprecated in API 23 I'm fully aware of that, can't go back so I have to fix the current code only. Below is only half code, the problem is if I'm trying to change the setLatestEventInfo everything else stops working. I'm really lost with what to change and how I would really be grateful if someone help me out. Going crazy over this from past two days. Thanks!

```
    private void EmergencyNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.pus_notification;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = "Emergency Alert";
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, null);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
    notification.vibrate = vibrate;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
    Class<?> statusbarManager = null;
    try {
        statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Method showsb = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            try {
                showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            showsb.invoke(sbservice);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383287/notification-cannot-resolve-symbol-setlasteveninfo/34383451#34383451 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345768/cannot-resolve-method-setlatesteventinfo

Comment: I'm aware of those answers but unable to implement them in my code it changes the whole thing then my project doesn't work. @CommonsWare

Comment: Then edit your question, provide your implementation that "changes the whole thing", and explain in detail what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir what I'm trying to ask is how can I change just setLatestEventInfo method only without changing the whole code because  the code is used everywhere I can't make change the overall code just need to fix the deprecated method that's the problem.

Comment: There is nothing obvious from your code that would prevent you from using these builders. Switching to `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder` would affect 8 lines of code (from `new Notification()` through the call to `notify()`) in your code snippet from your question. "the code is used everywhere" -- then perhaps you should fix that, to remove the code duplication.